# Preservation of the en- prefix form of Latin negative prefix in-, in enemy & enmity

Tags: etymology, prefixes, morphology, negative-prefixes

The *en-* in *enemy* is a prefix meaning "not": the origin is Latin *inimicus,* from *in-* + *amicus* — a "not friend" or an "unfriend" ([Online Etymology Dictionary—enemy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=enemy)).

The Latin *in-* changed to *en-* when the word passed through French and into English. Compare *enmity,* which keeps the *en-* form, and *inimical,* which is the same origin, but uses *in-.* I assume the difference here is the difference in their relative dates of entry into English. The Online Etymology Dictionary dates *enemy* to early 13c. and *inimical* to the 1640s.

In the entry for *[in-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-),* the Online Etymology Dictionary notes:

> In Old French and Middle English often *en-,* but most of these forms have not
>   survived in Modern English, and the few that do (*enemy,* for instance) no
>   longer are felt as negative. The rule of thumb in English has been to use *in-* with obviously Latin elements, *un-* with native or nativized ones.

By "these forms have not survived", does this mean the prefixes were changed to *in-,* or have these words disappeared altogether? Why did this change occur? Are there any other examples of the *en-* form surviving as a negative prefix besides *enemy* and *enmity*?

Comment: The only other example I can think of is *envy*.

Comment: @deadrat: That's from the other *in-* prefix.

Comment: @sumelic I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: *[entire](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/entire?q=entire).*

Long answer:

### The two Latin prefixes *in-*: negative and prepositional

There are two Latin prefixes that have the same form *in-* (or *im-* before *p,b,* or *m*; *ir-* before *r,* and *il-* before *l*). One of them has a negative meaning (it is cognate to and has a similar meaning to the English negative prefix *un-*). Examples of words with this suffix: ***in***valid, **im**mature, **ir**relevant, **il**literate. The other has a vague but generally prepositional meaning, as it was derived from the Latin preposition *in* (which is cognate to and has a similar meaning to the English preposition *in*). Examples of words with this suffix: ***in***cident, **im**pulse, **ir**ritate, **il**lustrate.

There are many words in English that start with *en-* or *em-* derived from the Latin prepositional prefix *in-* (such as *envy,* *endure* and *embrace*).

However, your question is about the negative prefix in particular.

### Development in French of the Latin negative prefix *in-*

The change of Latin *in-* to French *en-* is in accordance with the regular sound change of Latin short /i/ to Proto Western Romance /e/ (shown in a table on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#Table_of_vowel_outcomes)). However, it seems that in general, the negative prefix *en-* ended up being replaced by *in-* (in both French and English). As your quote says, in general, the negative meaning of *en-* is not obvious in the words that retained the prefix. I found a description of this change with some examples here: *[Principles of English Etymology: The foreign element](https://books.google.com/books?id=lKERAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=%22negative%20prefix%22%20enfant%20entire&source=bl&ots=J3U8F0eoQD&sig=t4pLOzQBJwZjXB4jFVLITxxGQHM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLu_36hOXLAhXDm4MKHU3iCUkQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22negative%20prefix%22%20enfant%20entire&f=false)*, by Walter William Skeat.

I don't know why *in-* ended up being more common than *en-* in French, despite not following the normal laws of sound change. It may be due to the influence of Latin spelling. French has a lot of learned words that do not show all of the usual sound changes from Latin. This is particularly common for adjectives; for example, the corresponding adjective to the noun *école* "school" is *scolaire*. (A somewhat comparable phenomenon in English is "[collateral adjectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_adjective)" such as *cow* and *bovine.*) And it seems to me that in both English and French, negative prefixes such as "in-" and "un-" are most commonly used on adjectives.

If French ended up with more words borrowed from Latin with *in-* than words inherited from Latin with *en-*, that might have been a reason why speakers gradually regularized the words starting with *en-* to make them have the more common, synonymous prefix *in-*.

### Examples of negative *en-* in English: *enemy, enmity, entire*

I found only one example in Modern English besides *enemy* and *enmity*: *[entire](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/entire?q=entire)*, which comes from Latin *integrum* (meaning "whole," compositionally from "untouched"). I learned of this example from W. H. H. Kelke's "[An Epitome of English Grammar For the Use of Students, Adapted to the London Matriculation Course and Similar Examinations](https://books.google.com/books?id=qYAvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=negative%20prefix%20%22en%22%20enemy&source=bl&ots=3O2SyHjKOc&sig=B2AYSZPKeP6eJdTeMNalylHEzyY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6sP_sqL7LAhVpv4MKHTdCDwIQ6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q=negative%20prefix%20%22en%22%20enemy&f=false)."

Kelke also mentions *enfecte,* used by Chaucer as a spelling of "infect." The normal verb *infect* seems to come from the Latin verb *inficio* "to dye, stain, poison" which has the prepositional prefix rather than the negative prefix. However, there apparently was a Latin adjective [*infectus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infectus#Latin) which Wiktionary defines as "not done, unfinished; impossible" and which has the negative prefix. If Chaucer's "enfecte" is in fact an example of the negative prefix "en-," as Kelke says, I guess it must descend from this Latin word.

### Examples of negative *en-* in French and Anglo-French

On the French side, one more word with *en-* from Latin negative *in-* is *enfant,* which compositionally comes from "not speaking." In Modern English, this word has become *[infant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=infant&allowed_in_frame=0),* but according to the Oxford English Dictionary spellings like *enfaunt, enfant* used to be used. The Modern French word, which retains the spelling with *en-,* has been borrowed into English more recently in phrases like *enfant terrible.*

In addition, Skeat lists some Anglo-French forms with negative *en-*: *enferme* "infirm" and *enfermité* "infirmity." However, the equivalent words in modern French are spelled with *in-*: *[infirme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/infirme)* and *[infirmité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/infirmite).*

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the extract from Etymonline, ***in*** is the original prefix, which became **en** in French. English finally adopted "in" for words of Latin origin and the more common **un** for Anglo-Saxons ones. The prefix en- still survives with other connotations:

***[En-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/en-)***:

> - ***a prefix occurring originally in loanwords from French and productive in English on this model, forming verbs with the general sense*** “to cause (a person or thing) to be in” the place, condition, or state named by the stem; more specifically, “to confine in or place on” ( enshrine; enthrone; entomb); “to cause to be in” ( enslave; entrust; enrich; encourage; endear); “to restrict” in the manner named by the stem, typically with the additional sense “on all sides, completely” ( enwind; encircle; enclose; entwine). ***This prefix is also attached to verbs in order to make them transitive, or to give them a transitive marker if they are already transitive ( enkindle; enliven; enshield; enface).***

Enemy:

> - from ***[in](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-&allowed_in_frame=0)***- "not" (see in- (1)) + amicus "friend" related to amare
> - ***The rule of thumb in English has been to use in- with obviously Latin elements, un- with native or nativized ones.***

The prefix **in-** is actually less  common than **un-**   but still used:

[Un](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=un-&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - The most prolific of English prefixes, freely and widely used in Old English, where it forms more than 1,000 compounds. It underwent a mass extinction in early Middle English, but emerged with renewed vigor 16c. to form compounds with native and imported words. ***It disputes with Latin-derived cognate in- (1) the right to form the negation of certain words (indigestable/undigestable, etc.), and though both might be deployed in cooperation to indicate shades of meaning (unfamous/infamous), typically they are not.***

Comment: I think you have confused in- (1) with in- (2). The first is a negative, the second is related to the preposition "in".

Comment: @fdb     where do I mention 'in' as a preposition in my answer?

Comment: You don't, but you should have. "Entrust" etc. is from in- (2). "Enemy" is from in- (1).

Comment: @fdb - I mention that part just to show the the profit is still actually used with a different connotation.